# On Karp reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Assume a complete problem for a class $\mathcal C$ is in $P/poly$ and at each $n$ assume that the advice string is $s_n$ of length $n^c$ for a fixed $c>0$.

Assume that $SAT$ of $n$ length input Turing reduces to the following problem

> Given $a\in\Bbb N$ is $s_n>a$?

then does ${NP}\in P/poly$ hold?

If it Karp reduces to this problem does $P=NP$ hold?

If $SAT$ Karp reduces to $\mathcal C$ then ${NP}\in P/poly$ holds. What if $SAT$ just Turing reduces to $\mathcal C$?

Comment: What would it take to implement an oracle for that "following problem"? ​ (Also, the line after that problem has a type error.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I am not sure how to implement an oracle in general.

Comment: What class will that "following problem" be in? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer That is what confuses me. It does not seem to be in $NP$.

Comment: @RickyDemer Am I wrong in this?